# PhpStorm Testing: "Connection was not established. 'Xdebug 3.2.0' extension is installed. Check configuration options."

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

## My Settings

- PhpStorm Version: 2022.3.2
- macOS: 13.2.1 (22D68)

### php.ini XDEBUG Config

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="xdebug.so"
xdebug.mode=develop,coverage,debug,profile
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.log=/dev/stdout
xdebug.log_level=0
xdebug.client_port=9001
xdebug.client_host=127.0.0.1
```

## Scenario

I am trying to debug a Pest test in PhpStorm for a Laravel 9 project. I have no problem running it, but when I set a breakpoint on what I'm testing and debug it instead, I get the following outcome.

## Outcome

[image: debugger is waiting for incoming connection]

[image: connection was not established]

[image: xdebug was installed, but connection not established]

Comment: 1) Check what Xdebug log has to say about it. It's the first / main step. 2) You Xdebug settings in PhpStorm -- show them. Especially the ports. Make sure that `9001` is listed on first place if there are more than one listed there. Ideally have only 1 there.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [LazyOne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/783119/lazyone)'s comment.

I had three ports. 9000, 9001, and 9003. I changed it to only 9001, and now it's working.